# Pandas Left outer join with exclusions

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, transformation

I am looking to do a left outer join and return rows that are in left table and not in right table.
I tried df=pd.merge(left,right,on['id','date1','date2'],how="outer",indicator=True)

df = df[df['_merge'] == 'left_only']
but it did not work.

```
df1:
  id      date1       date2    sold
   1     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   22
   2     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   12
   3     8/12/2021   8/11/2021   18
   4     8/13/2021   8/11/2021   14
   5     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   10


df2:
   id      date1       date2    sold
   3     8/12/2021   8/11/2021   18
   4     8/13/2021   8/11/2021   14
   5     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   10
   6     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   30



desired output:
  id      date1       date2     sold
   1     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   22
   2     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   12
```

Comment: Didn't work?  What happened?

Comment: instead of retaining the same 4 columns, it created  'sold_x' and 'sold_y' and listed all 6 IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from io import StringIO

textfile1 = StringIO("""  id      date1       date2    sold
   1     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   22
   2     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   12
   3     8/12/2021   8/11/2021   18
   4     8/13/2021   8/11/2021   14
   5     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   10""")

textfile2 = StringIO("""   id      date1       date2    sold
   3     8/12/2021   8/11/2021   18
   4     8/13/2021   8/11/2021   14
   5     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   10
   6     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   30
""")

df1 = pd.read_csv(textfile1, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
df2 = pd.read_csv(textfile2, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

df_out = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator='ind').query('ind == "left_only"')
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   id      date1      date2  sold        ind
0   1  8/11/2021  8/11/2021    22  left_only
1   2  8/11/2021  8/11/2021    12  left_only
```

Note, if you don't use join columns `pd.DataFrame.merge` will use common named columns to join on.

Update:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from io import StringIO

textfile1 = StringIO(
    """  id      date1       date2    sold
   1     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   22
   2     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   12
   3     8/12/2021   8/11/2021   18
   4     8/13/2021   8/11/2021   14
   5     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   10"""
)

textfile2 = StringIO(
    """   id      date1       date2    sold
   3     8/12/2021   8/11/2021   18
   4     8/13/2021   8/11/2021   14
   5     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   10
   6     8/11/2021   8/11/2021   30
"""
)

df1 = pd.read_csv(textfile1, sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
df2 = pd.read_csv(textfile2, sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

df_out = (
    df1.merge(df2, how="outer", indicator="ind", on="id", suffixes=("", "_y"))
    .query('ind == "left_only"')
    .reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)
)
df_out
```

Output:

```
   id      date1      date2  sold
0   1  8/11/2021  8/11/2021  22.0
1   2  8/11/2021  8/11/2021  12.0
```

Comment: is there a way to specify on what columns to join in this statement?

Comment: Yes, but if youhave other columns you will get the _x and _y duplicate columns.  Use `on` if the join columns are the same in both dataframes or you can use `left_on` and `right_on`  to join on different named columns in each dataframe.